# Heroku deployment, git remote not added

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I'm new to Heroku, trying to follow the "Getting Started with NodeJS tutorial" and I got stuck at the "[Deploy your App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app)" stage.

When I run "heroku create" I do not get "Git remote heroku added". I realized it was missing after trying the "git push heroku master" step and getting "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git". What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please do following command then enter:

```
git init
```

After that you can `git push heroku master` again

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and after "git push heroku master" I get a message about permission issues as follows: "Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists." What should I do?

Comment: I made it! Basically I created a key with the following command: "heroku keys:add". Then "Could not find an existing public key at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Would you like to generate one? [Yn] y
Generating new SSH public key." After that I tried "git push heroku master" again and it worked!

Comment: Marked as accepted, unfortunately I don't have the required rep to upvote you sorry.

Comment: I had the same problem on win10 and running "git init" again solved my problem. Upvoting both question and answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

One can go into the root of the app and run following command:

```
heroku git:remote -a 'app-name e.g radiant-garden-35190'
```

after that run following to see all the remotes associated with your app :

```
git remote -v
```

You should get a response like this :

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/radiant-garden-35190.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/radiant-garden-35190.git (push)
```

You might not see the remote for your github if you have not committed your app yet.

Answer (score 3):

To extend the answer from @tien-nguyen. An empty git repository should be initialized after running this:

```
git init
```

If running this right away:

```
git push heroku master
```

It will return this:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'heroku'
```

Very likely this is due to nothing is staged to be pushed. Add files, commit and try push again should fix the issue.

```
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push heroku master
```

This should commit and push the files into the repo.

In the case where git remote is not yet defined. Use the following:

```
heroku git:remote -a <name of the heroku app>
git remote -v
```

This should list out the remote url, should look something like this:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/<name of the heroku app>.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/<name of the heroku app>.git (push)
```

Now proceed with add, commit and push again.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you need to run this command `heroku git:remote -a project_name` under your project folder

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a custom remote name:

```
heroku git:remote --app my-heroku-app-name -r my-custom-remote-name
```

Comment: this is helpful especially I am adding second heroku remote to same git repo

Answer (score 1):

After running `heroku create my-amazing-app`, you should see a response with the web url along with the git url. Use the git url (something like git.heroku.../my-amazing-app.git) to add the remote yourself like so:

`git remote add heroku git.heroku.../my-amazing-app.git`

Then running `git remote -v` should show the new remote with heroku.

Answer (score 0):

```
'heroku git:remote --app $appname'
```

This command does the trick to add to git remote if not added while 'heroku create'.